# Cannot post React registration form input to my ASP.NET Core 3.1 backend to update SQL Server database

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

I am brand new at Stack Overflow and fairly new to coding. I am creating an e-commerce site for my capstone school project and I have successfully created the database in SQL Server. I have also created the API controller(s), and the frontend using React.

I am able to input data in the React app registration form and upon submitting I can see that react has taken the information but then right after that I get an error message.

I have tried different things and sometimes I will get this message:

> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
>
> xhr.js:251     POST http://localhost:56400/api/Registration/Registration net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Other times I will get a 404 error depending on where I open the web page from. I used Visual Studio Code to create my frontend but I also linked it with Visual Studio 2019 where instead of the Weather page I get the react page after I execute the program. Both react app and visual studio are using Chrome. Here is what I get when I execute using Visual Studio 2019.

```
POST http://localhost:56400/api/Registration/Registration 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:251
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:148
httpMethod @ Axios.js:187
wrap @ bind.js:5
handleSave @ Registration.js:40
onClick @ Registration.js:131
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Registration.js:45 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong but here is my code from front end and back end for reference:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace *********_.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RegistrationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public RegistrationController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Registration")]
        public Response Registration(Registration registration)
        {
            Response response = new Response();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString").ToString());

            DAL dal = new DAL();
            response = dal.Registration(registration, connection);

            return response;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public Response Login(Registration registration)
        {
            Response response = new Response();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString").ToString());

            DAL dal = new DAL();
            response = dal.Login(registration, connection);

            return response;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UserApproval")]
        public Response UserApproval(Registration registration)
        {
            Response response = new Response();

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString").ToString());
            DAL dal = new DAL();

            response = dal.UserApproval(registration, connection);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace **********_.Models
{
    public class Registration
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string Apartment { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }

        public int IsApproved { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserNavBar from './UserNavBar';
import EWholism_Image2 from './EWholism_Image2.jpg';

function Registration() {
  
  const [FirstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
  const [LastName, setLastName] = useState('')
  const [StreetAddress, SetStreetAddress] = useState('')
  const [Apartment, setApartment] = useState('')
  const [City, setCity] = useState('')
  const [ZipCode, setZipCode] = useState('')
  const [Country, setCountry] = useState('')
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [Phone, setPhone] = useState('')

  const handleSave =(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, Apartment, City, ZipCode, Country, Email, Password, Phone);
    const url ='http://localhost:56400/api/Registration/Registration';
    const data = {
      FirstName : FirstName,
      LastName : LastName,
      StreetAddress : StreetAddress,
      Apartment : Apartment,
      City : City,
      ZipCode : ZipCode,
      Country : Country,
      Email : Email,
      Password : Password,
      Phone : Phone
    }

    axios.post(url,data)
    .then((result) => {
      const dt = result.data;
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
    
  return(
    <div>
      
       <UserNavBar />
      
         <section class="vh-200">
            <div class="container-fluid">
        
              <img class= "mindBody" src={EWholism_Image2} alt="EWholism_Image2" />
        
              <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-7 text-black">
        
                  <div class="px-5 ms-xl-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-crow fa-2x me-3 pt-5 mt-xl-4" style={{color: "#709085"}}></i>
                    <span class="h1 fw-bold mb-0">Logo</span>
                  </div>
        
                  <div class="d-flex align-items-center h-custom-2 px-5 ms-xl-4 mt-5 pt-5 pt-xl-0 mt-xl-n5">
        
                    <form style={{width: "23rem"}}>
            
                      <h3 class="fw-normal mb-5" style={{color: "#4835d4"}}>Register Here</h3>
                      
                      <div class="form-outline">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="FirstName">First name</label>

                      </div>
            
                      <div class="form-outline">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="LastName">Last name</label>
                      </div>                 
            
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => SetStreetAddress(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="StreetAddress">Street Address</label>
                      </div>
                                        
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setApartment(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="Apartment">Apartment/Suit #</label>
                      </div>
            
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="City">City</label>
                      </div>
                                        
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setZipCode(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="ZipCode">Zip Code</label>
                      </div>
                                        
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="Country">Country</label>
                      </div>
            
                      <br />         
                        
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="Phone">Phone Number</label>
                      </div>
            
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="Email">Your Email</label>
                      </div>
            
                      <div class="form-outline form-white">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                        <label class="form-label" for="Password">Create a passowrd..</label>
                      </div>
            
                      <div class="pt-1 mb-4">
                        <button onClick={(e) => handleSave(e)}>Register</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
     </div>
  )
}

export default Registration;
```

At first I was using the https SSL url so I unchecked SSL and am now using the http url. I then checked to make sure CORS are enabled. They are enabled. Lastly, I added the WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0 to my .env file in React.

I have checked to also make sure that my Visual Studio and SQL Server are connected. I can view my SQL Server tables in Visual Studio.